# Jersey: Display possible actions on a resource

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am using the Jersey implementation of JAX-RS spec to develop RESTful web services. There is a url that can uniquely identify a resource. Is there a way to let know the user of the RESTful services, the possible actions that can be performed on the resource? For example,

Resource name - host1

```
http://localhost:8080/state-fetcher/rest/object/host1/actions
```

This should give me all the possible actions that can be performed on the resource - {actions: [GET, POST, DELETE]}

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `OPTIONS` HTTP method on the resource. You will get the allowed methods in `Allow` header, for example: `Allow: GET, HEAD, PUT` and in a payload you will find the fragment of wadl associeted with the specified resource.

Answer (score 0):

A RESTful service itself is inteded to be self- descriptive! If the user performs a request, the REST service should send back a list of possible links, which can be performed next, along with the response. That's the motivation and general concept of a RESTful serivice. If you provide a graphical WebClient, you just need to provide the initial link (e.g. http:\example.com\restful), and the response sends back a list of valid links which just needs to be visualized within the GUI. Usually the webservice only provides those links which are accessible in terms of the users role. **(This is not a security feature!!! It just prevents that unecessary links are displayed)** Otherwise the OPTION method of the HTTP protocol provides information concerning the supported protocol methods.